# Ansible rolling restart multi cluster environment

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have a use case where I want to execute a rolling restart in multiple clusters. As the first step, I have created a task to execute serially on the hosts passed to the task which will execute the restart one node at a time. Currently, it takes O(n) time for node restart assuming the total number of nodes in all the cluster is n and constant time for node restart. I want to optimize the execution of this ansible job such that the task to restart nodes is executed serially in the cluster but in parallel across the clusters resulting in effective restart time proportional to the maximum number of hosts in a cluster. Example of the given inventory -

```
[Cluster_1]
host_1_a
host_1_b

[Cluster_2]
host_2_a
host_2_b

[Cluster_3]
host_3_a
host_3_b
host_3_c
```

The current execution time is 7*(reboot_time) and I want to optimize it to 3*(reboot_time). I am not sure if this possible in ansible and would welcome any suggestions. Thanks!

Ansible playbook to restart service:

```yaml
- name: Rolling reboot
  hosts: all
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: stop service
      service:
        name: xyz
        state: stopped

    - name: start service
      service:
        name: xyz
        state: started

    - name: wait for service to start
      uri:
        url: "http://localhost:8081/node-health"
        method: GET
      register: http_status
      until: http_status.status == 200
      retries: 60
      delay: 10
```

Comment: Can you give an example playbook that currently does serial among all the hosts?

Comment: Not sure if this might be helpful for you, but note that serial is not just a yes/no, you can also have more than one host per batch, or control the batches with arrays and percentages: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size

Comment: @AndyShinn added the playbook

Answer (score 2):

A very easy way to approach this would be to launch the playbook in parallel once for each cluster. This would actually be my preferred solution.

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory -l Cluster_1 playbook.yml 2>&1 > mylog1.txt &
ansible-playbook -i inventory -l Cluster_2 playbook.yml 2>&1 > mylog2.txt &
ansible-playbook -i inventory -l Cluster_3 playbook.yml 2>&1 > mylog3.txt &
```

Meanwhile, if you really want to keep this in a single run, here is a (possible start of a) solution. The idea is to dynamically create a list of servers mixing your existing cluster servers lists. Note that this is absolutely not bullet proof and making it totally scalable might end up in a nightmare.

Here it is anyway if this can give you some ideas. The key is the creation of the list with the [`zip_longest` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters), then mapping the [`select` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) to remove null values and flattening the final result.

```yaml
---
- name: Create a dynamic group mixing hosts from each cluster
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups:
          - all_clusters_imbricated
      loop: "{{ groups['Cluster_1'] | zip_longest(groups['Cluster_2'], groups['Cluster_3']) | list | map('select') | map('list') | flatten }}"

- name: Loop serially over all clusters
  hosts: all_clusters_imbricated
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 3

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: I would restart host {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

Which gives with your current example inventory:

```
PLAY [Create a dynamic group mixing hosts from each cluster] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [add_host] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=host_1_a)
changed: [localhost] => (item=host_2_a)
changed: [localhost] => (item=host_3_a)
changed: [localhost] => (item=host_1_b)
changed: [localhost] => (item=host_2_b)
changed: [localhost] => (item=host_3_b)
changed: [localhost] => (item=host_3_c)

PLAY [Loop serially over all clusters] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host_1_a] => {
    "msg": "I would restart host host_1_a"
}
ok: [host_2_a] => {
    "msg": "I would restart host host_2_a"
}
ok: [host_3_a] => {
    "msg": "I would restart host host_3_a"
}

PLAY [Loop serially over all clusters] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host_1_b] => {
    "msg": "I would restart host host_1_b"
}
ok: [host_2_b] => {
    "msg": "I would restart host host_2_b"
}
ok: [host_3_b] => {
    "msg": "I would restart host host_3_b"
}

PLAY [Loop serially over all clusters] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host_3_c] => {
    "msg": "I would restart host host_3_c"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
host_1_a                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_1_b                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_2_a                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_2_b                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_3_a                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_3_b                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_3_c                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```